# pushViewController:animated doesn't show any animation - Objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, viewcontroller

I'm trying to push a new view controller on screen with an animation but this doesn't work. I use this code :

```
PhotosViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:vcID];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

But even by setting `animated:YES` there is no animation. 
Do you know what can cause this ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: may be your PhotosViewController loads fast

Comment: Check if it's running on the main thread.

Comment: @teixeiras well done ! Thanks :)